# How to set div width to 100%

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to design a 2 column layout using divs. My left column size is fixed to `150 px`. But right column is not fixed size, so I want it to extend to right boundary of the browser. I used `width:auto` and `width:100%` values in right column but they didn't work.

CSS :

> ```
>  html {
>     height:100%; width:100%
> }
> body {
>     color: #000040; 
>     text-align: left; 
>     padding:0; 
>     margin:0; 
>     height:100%; 
>     width:100%
> }
> #header {
>     position:relative; 
>     float:left; 
>     background-color: #000053; 
>     width: 100%; 
>     height: 76px
> }
> #wrapper {
>   position:relative; 
>   overflow:hidden; 
>   width:100%; 
>   height: 100%; 
>   margin:0px auto; 
>   padding:0; 
>   background-color:Aqua
> }
> #container {
>     clear:left; 
>     float:left; 
>     overflow:hidden; 
>     width:100%; 
>     height:100%
> }
> #left_column {
>     position: relative; 
>     float: left; 
>     background-color:Fuchsia; 
>     width: 150px; 
>     overflow:hidden; 
>     height:100%
> }
> #right_column {
>     position: relative; 
>     float:left; 
>     overflow:hidden; 
>     background-color:Blue; 
>     height: 100%; 
>     width:auto }
> ```

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"> 
            <div id="header">
               HEADER
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="left_column">
                    LEFT COLUMN
                </div>
                <div id="right_column">
                    RIGHT COLUMN
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would remove all `position` statements and only put a `float:left` on the left column, not the right nor the container. Give the right column a `margin-left:150px` and it should work fine.

Except for the left-floated column, you can also remove the `width:100%` statements from the rest; when they're not floated, they'll be 100% wide automatically.

The `overflow:hidden` is only needed on the wrapper; at least if you are using it to have the `div` grow in height to accommodate the floats inside it.

Answer (score 1):

change for the div right_column the position from relative to fixed, and width from auto to 100%. Also add left:150px;
With these changes you css for right_column will look like the following:

```
#right_column {
        position: fixed;
        left:150px;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:Blue;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%; }
```

you can check it here http://jsbin.com/ejetu3

Comment: It works well but it has a problem with scrolling. I tried to remove overflow hidden tags to see what happens when the page needs to be scrolled. When I scroll down the page, right column doesn't scroll down..

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow

overflow is already buggy in internet explorer :(